# Referencing column name rather than field

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I'm designing a database for a healthcare application. I have a table in which I register every blood test done to a patient, with columns such as PatientID, Date, Hemoglobin, WhiteBCellCount, Oxygen (etc..), meaning that the value for each element is stored in a different column.
But I also have a table with reference values. The columns are: ID, Element, Value.

In this way, the Element field for the reference values table is actually the name of one of several columns in the test result table, which I think could be an issue when querying the DB. Which would be a more proper way to design these tables?

I could make a table to assign a code and name to each element, but I don't know how I could link it to the test results table. I wouldn't want to change the design of the test result table, since all the blood elements are registered everytime, I think having a column for each is ok, but I'm open to suggestions regarding best practices in this subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not want to be comparing columns in one table to column names in another.

I would recommend that you change how you store the base data for each patient.  Instead of using different columns, have three basic columns:

- `PatientId`
- `TestName` (or `TestId`)
- `Value`

Then you can store the reference values in another table, something like:

- `TestName` (or `TestId`)
- `RangeLow`
- `RangeHigh`

This will make it easy to match the reference values to the tests.  It will also make it easy to add new tests.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing this, but I wonder:  if I added a column called VisitID or something like that to group all the results from a single sample, would it still be considered a 3rd normal form? (Using the date won't do because we can either have several samples from one day or obtain results from one sample over the course of several days)

Comment: @Fernanda . . . Definitely.  You can have the `visitId` on the test results and then a separate table that has information -- such as the `patientId` for the visit.